# Jobs ordering is corrupted

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I opened **search jobs** page, sorted it by the **newest** and opened the last page available (7).

What I received was that the 2 most recent jobs were shown on this page - at the end of the list, but instead they should be at the beginning - on the first page (1).

[image]

I cannot reproduce this bug already, but I believe, that it should be reported anyway.

**UPDATE:**

Today I've encountered this bug again:

[image]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I've just encountered this issue again. It seems that it takes place for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Also you have a reopen vote about your own question.